# UI Multi select customise order drag drop

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I have a custom Pagebuilder component with a category selector that manages a front end carousel component, what I want to do is to set the order of the selection, this is currently tied to the category ID which in turn will set the order on the front end.

I have looked at the datascope, currently 'category_ids' but cannot see where to add a custom filter or how I can enable drag and drop reordering to control the front end output.

I have gone through the Adobe docs and cannot see any option to add or enable this.

Just pointers would be really helpful here.

thanks

```
<field name="category_ids" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category" sortOrder="18" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <label translate="true">Categories</label>
            <notice translate="true">Please specify categories you want to display on the frontend.</notice>
            <dataScope>category_ids</dataScope>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="validate-category-thumbnail-image" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-action-multiselect-category-ids">false</class>
            </additionalClasses>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to reorder the categories in your custom Pagebuilder component, and based on your code snippet, you're using Magento's built-in UI component for category selection.

There's no out-of-the-box support for drag-and-drop reordering in Magento's category selector, but here are some pointers on how you can implement custom ordering:

1. **Custom UI Component**:

   - Create a custom UI component extending Magento's default component, e.g., `Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category`.
   - Implementing the reordering functionality in the component. You can leverage libraries such as jQuery UI's `sortable` to achieve this.
2. **Store Order in Additional Field**:

   - After allowing drag-and-drop functionality, you need to save the order. An approach is to save the reordered list of category IDs as a comma-separated string in a field.
   - You can then use this field to determine the order of categories on the frontend.
3. **Modify Frontend Carousel Component**:

   - Modify your frontend carousel component to accept and use the order from the  field (or wherever you store the ordered list of category IDs).
   - Ensure your custom ordering is preserved and used during frontend rendering.
4. **Backend Data Processing**:

   - In your backend processing code (usually in a Model or Controller), make sure to account for the custom order when saving and retrieving the ordered list of categories.

You could add a dedicated "Sort Order" field for each category in your component.